# Portable wrappers for GNU, BSD, etc. versions of tools

Tags: gnu, bsd

Is there any script that provides a compatibility layer to a subset (a rich subset would be best of course) of BSD and GNU commands?

As an example, possible cases handled could include:

- dd and its incompatible `M` vs `m` block size indicator
- ping and its incompatible `-w` vs `-W` wait time option

Comment: If you were going to create yet another version of a command in order to mitigate incompatibilities between existing versions of the command, I'm pretty sure [this](http://xkcd.com/927/) would apply.

Comment: @Celada: if it was to be their private standard, the perspective changes -- they would develop a solution to the remaining 14 standards, not another standard :)

Comment: This might not even be possible in [some cases](http://askubuntu.com/questions/554118/tr-convert-apostrophe-to-ascii).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not such a script.

You basically have 2 choices:

1. Just use the subset of options POSIX specifies. Note that it can even be challenging to get the POSIX conforming shell binary in a portable way. For example, `/bin/sh` doesn't have to be conforming. The portable way to get a POSIX conforming shell is: `PATH=$(getconf PATH) command -v sh`
2. Just install GNU versions everywhere and use those.

Comment: @mikeserv, that is my point - even something simple as finding the POSIX conforming `sh` is quite challenging. But `getconf` is specified by POSIX, though. As always, you have to decide how portable you want to be. Portable down to ancient UNIX machines? Strictly ortable to POSIX version X? Portable to relevant Linux/BSD/UNIX systems?

Comment: @mikeserv, you don't expect a POSIX conforming `getconf` in the current PATH (or builtin, shell function etc.) but you expect that instead a conforming `command` is there. This is just an arbitrary assumption.

Comment: Very good point. That is what I meant by *(you're probably already pretty close)* and that is exactly the point made in `man command`'s *Rationale* when discussing the `getconf` script in `man sh`'s *Examples*. Your answer is correct - and had my upvote yesterday - my only quibble was with `which` vs `command` - which you fixed. Thank you. The rest was just argument for arguments' sake - though, I was in part reinforcing your statement - it can be very difficult to be sure about environment without some baseline. And so I think clear dependencies are the best option in most cases.