# Which shells don't support dollar-parenthesis expansion, and demand backticks?

Tags: shell, command-substitution, portability

The modern recommendation is to use:

```
$(...)
```

instead of the older:

```
`...`
```

mainly for readability and to avoid the need for escaping when nesting.

Which shells do not support the `$(...)` form, and are any of them still in use today?

Comment: Read through [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) and you will find the answer.

Comment: It says "The only reason for using backticks is for compatibility with a real Bourne shell (like Heirloom)."

Comment: One important point is that all maintained post-90's  Unix-like systems will have a command called `sh` which in the right environment will support `$(...)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original Bourne shell, csh or tcsh all do not support `$()` and require ``` `` ```  for command substitution.

The Bourne shell is no longer used as the default shell (/bin/sh) on many UNIX based operating systems. However, these shells are still supplied by the OS vendors as they are still used for historical reasons.

Both AIX and HP-UX have /bin/sh as a POSIX compliant shell. Bourne shell is still available on AIX as 'bsh' (but deprecated in [1995](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~wellings/tipspit/aix41.html#bsh) with AIX 4.1) and HP-UX 11.11 '/usr/old/bin/sh' (Bourne was removed from 11.23). I'm not sure when the switch was made, but it was many years ago.

Answer (score 5):

The Solaris 10 and earlier `/bin/sh` does not support `$()`.

It is still in use today because Solaris 10 is still in use, Sun did not want to replace it with a standard conforming version (up to and including Solaris 10) - and because most people consider `/bin/sh` as the default shell and [don't know how to portably execute a script with a POSIX conforming shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170836/1131).

Sun's motivation for not changing `/bin/sh` was to avoid breaking existing shell scripts that rely on the non-conforming behavior.

Comment: @cuonglm, yes, I just tested it and I can confirm it. Would have thought that rather Hurd is going to be released than Sun/Oracle changes its policy on `/bin/sh` ...