# Appending One File to the Second Until End of File

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, scripting

I have two files. The first is just a single number. This number is calculated and changes every time. The second file has a bunch of columns, and I do not know the number of rows (which can change). For example, I have something like this:

File 1:

```
12
```

File 2:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I want

```
1 2 3 12
4 5 6 12
7 8 9 12
```

My thoughts are that you could do a `while not EOF` then `cat File 1` and `File 2`. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4):

Another `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{getline l <"file1"};{print $0, l}' file2
1 2 3 12
4 5 6 12
7 8 9 12
```

- `BEGIN` block was executed first before reading input file. The first line in `file1` was retrieve using `getline()` function, stored in variable `l`
- With each line of `file2`, we print it content `$0` along with `l`, separated by `OFS`, which is a space by default.

Comment: Works great, thank you! Would you mind explaining exactly what is going on? :)

Comment: @dani If this solved your problem (or one of the other answers) you shoudl accept it (by clicking the check mark next to the answer)  That will let others know the question has been resolved, let others with the same question know what worked for you and give both you and the answerer more reputation

Answer (score 2):

### Using awk

```
$ awk -v n=$(cat file1) '{print $0,n}' file2
1 2 3 12
4 5 6 12
7 8 9 12
```

On `csh`/`tcsh`, try:

```
awk -v n=`cat file1` '{print $0,n}' file2
```

#### How it works

- `-v n=$(cat file1)`

  This assigns the contents of `file1` to the awk variable `n`.
- `print $0,n`

  This prints each line followed by `n`.

### Using sed

```
$ sed '1{h;d}; G;s/\n/ /' file1 file2
1 2 3 12
4 5 6 12
7 8 9 12
```

#### How it works

- `1{h;d}`

  The first line read is saved in the hold space and then deleted from that pattern space (so it doesn't print).
- `G; s/\n/ /`

  For all subsequent lines, we use the get command, `G`.  This appends to the patterns space a newline and the hold space.  We then replace that newline with a space.

Comment: Note that using `-v var=value` will expand escape sequence in `var`.

Comment: Thank you, although I think the awk should work, I get: "Illegal variable name." The sed command does work! I'd love to know why the awk command is not working? Also I should add I'm getting the same "Illegal variable name." error when I try to run the first two answers using sed. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @Dani That sounds like you are using [some shell like csh or tcsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/which-shells-dont-support-dollar-parenthesis-expansion-and-demand-backticks).  My awk and two of the other sed solutions use `$(...)` for command substitution.   This is supported by all POSIX compatible shells.  On csh, the `$(...)` notation needs to be replaced by backticks: see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (in this case file2 gets updated, if you don't want that, remove the -i flag)

```
   sed -i "s/.*/& $(cat file1)/" file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -e "s/ *\$/ $(cat file1)/" file2
1 2 3 12
4 5 6 12
7 8 9 12
```

Answer (score 0):

For `sed` lovers — read *file1* for each line in *file2* it is not good idea. Much better to use variable:

```
my_var=$(<file1) ; sed "s/$/ $my_var/" file2
```

or more secure

```
read -r my_var <file1 ; sed "s/$/ $my_var/" file2
```

Comment: When you say, *"read file1 for each line in file2 it is not good idea"*, are you referring to other `sed` answers wihch use  `$(cat file1)` within a `sed` expression?  If so, then, it is worth noting that `$(cat file1)` is expanded by the shell on the command line  so `sed` gets a literal value. – Also, what is more secure about using `read -r`? Though the `-r` disables  backshash(escape) sequence translation, a variable containing a backslash would be interpreted as an *escape* character (unless it was embedded in a character range expression, eg. `[abc\]`.

Comment: @Peter.O In *file1* can be more then 1 line thus it break out the script instead of `read` which takes 1 line only. Are you sure that `$(cat)` expanding is not provided for each line?

Comment: Ok, point taken. In that case, `$(head -n1 file1)` would be equivalent to the `read -r` method, and thereby *safer* than either `$(cat file1)` or `$(<file1)`.  Nonetheless, all these methods (including`read -r`) are subject to the *escape-sequence* interpretation. –  However, that being said, all 4 methods are fine, if the data is as per the stated specs.