# Using cut command for an environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, cut

I want to extract the host name of a machine and omit whatever exists after `.`. For example, the command `hostname` says `compute-0-0.local`. So, I used `cut command like this

```
# hostname | cut -f 1 -d "."
compute-0-0
```

Now, I want to put that output in a variable. The following command doesn't work.

```
# HT=`hostname` | cut -f 1 -d "."
# echo $HT
compute-0-0.local
```

Any way to fix that?

Comment: It is because the backticks are not around the whole command. Also prefer `$()` over backticks. see @clk 's answer for details on how.

Comment: Does `"${HOSTNAME%%.*}"` work for you? `HOSTNAME` is not in POSIX though

Comment: assuming Linux (or other OS with a reasonably modern and useful `hostname` command), you could just use `hostname -s` aka `hostname --short`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead, noting that your entire command must be enclosed within the backticks:

```
HT=`hostname | cut -f 1 -d "."`
```

You could potentially use `$()` as well:

```
HT=$(hostname | cut -f 1 -d ".")
```

This syntax for command substitution is not supported in [certain shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/which-shells-dont-support-dollar-parenthesis-expansion-and-demand-backticks), though, including the original Bourne shell, csh and tcsh. For those shells you will need to use backticks.

Comment: Note that backticks aren't always a matter of preference: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/which-shells-dont-support-dollar-parenthesis-expansion-and-demand-backticks

Comment: @DWORDPTR Thanks for mentioning that. I've updated my answer to reflect that.